# Why event is not working in javascript? The color of h1 is not changing by clicking button . Below is the link of image of code

Tags: events, event-handling, dom-events

Why event is not working in javascript? The color of h1 is not changing by clicking button  . Below is the link of image of code.[here is the link of image of code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BGeg.png)

Comment: "here is the link of image of code" - code is naturally text. Your question would be *much* better if you actually included the code as text *in the question*. For JavaScript, you can even include it as a code snippet that people trying to help you can run directly. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and make it as easy as possible for people to help you.

Comment: @shrikant Singh it is still not changing the color of h1

Comment: Rather than thanking me, please actually *edit the question* as requested. There's an Edit link just under the question - please use that to make the question more useful and answerable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1 id="hello">hello</h1>
<select name="select" id="select">
  <option value="black">black</option>
  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
</select>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    $('select').change(function(){
        field = document.querySelector('select');
        document.querySelector("#hello").style.backgroundColor = field.value;
       });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.